# How to access server aggregate on the client side within meteor

Tags: meteor

Bit of a noob question. I'm using [meteor-native-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-native-mongo) on the server to access the aggregate function in MongoDB, however, I'm not sure how I return and access the results on the client side. In the past subscribing and then accessing the collections on the client was pretty straightforward using the collection.find({}) function, however, I don't understand how to do it with the aggregate function. Can someone please explain.

```
Meteor.publish('companies', function(limit) {

  db.collection('companies').aggregate([{ $group: { _id: { location: "$google_maps.geometry_location" }, companies: { $addToSet: { name: "$company_name" } }, count: { $sum: 1} } }, { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }]).toArray((err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
  });

});
```

Comment: Create a [server-side method](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html) which will perform your aggregation and call that method from client side.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. What's the difference between a method and subscribing.

Comment: You can do processor intensive tasks on server side using server methods as well as eliminate sending data to client which you want don't wan't to give access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.added`, `this.changed`, `this.removed` from https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-added ...

```js
Meteor.publish('companies', function(limit) {
  var subscription = this;
  db.collection('companies').aggregate([{ $group: { _id: { location: "$google_maps.geometry_location" }, companies: { $addToSet: { name: "$company_name" } }, count: { $sum: 1} } }, { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }]).toArray((err, result) => {
      subscription.added('companies-aggregate', 'geometry-grouping', {result: result});
  });

});

// On the client:
var CompaniesAggregate = new Mongo.Collection('companies-aggregate');

// Inside a reactive context, like a helper
var result = CompaniesAggregate.findOne('geometry-grouping').result;
```

Naturally, to make it reactive, you'd have to know when the results of the aggregations would change. There is no automatic way to do that--you would have to resolve that logically, with your own code.

The best way to do that is to save the subscription variable in an array somewhere in a higher scope, and called `changed` on all the subscriptions for `'companies'` for the `geometry-grouping` document, computing an updated result.

The commenter's solution won't be realtime; in other words, if one user makes a change to the e.g. company name or location, another user won't see those changes.